# EF migration,to first select record based on some condition,store it in some varible for later utilization

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Say we have a table called as

```
Employee
___________________________________
ID | Name | Surname | DomainID
```

And another table

```
Domain
______________________
ID | Name | Type
```

where employee table has foreigh key to domain table

Now i want to write Entity Framwwork Migration such that whose domainID matched with filtering criteria and i want to change Domain.Type and say Employee.Surname.

Some thing like

```
1. var emp = Select all Employee where DomainID = 1;
   Store the result in some varibale 
2. loop through emp and do changes.
```

NOTE: I am using EntityFramework, and i dont want to create temporary tables to store data as it might be one time job.

Comment: what do you mean by write EF Migration, if you want to edit your data model and make changes reflect to database you don't need to write migrations yourself, you just use Nuget Console and run the migration commands "Add Migration" then "Update Database". Is this your case or you just want sample code on how to get the desired data and loop through it?

Comment: @mGouda:there is no model change,what i need is to update data based on some condition.

Comment: @AnshulNigam you can update data with another migration calling Sql("update ...") method. Or is your question about what SQL command would look like here?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the below will do the trick

```
private void YourMethod(int domainId)
 {
 var filteredEmployees = Emoployees.Where(e=>e.DomainID == domainId).ToList();
    foreach(Employee emp in filteredEmployees)
    {
       //do your logic
     }
     YourDBContext.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Comment: I need to do migration using Entity Framework and there you dont have linq available, so basically its sql with limitation.

Comment: sorry, it seems I still didn't get your request. I got you want to update subset of your data based on domain criteria. do you want to do the job using EF or SQL?

Comment: EF has a way to deploy your table and seed it is through migrations , so i wanted to use that. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application